# Stripe Checkout - VueJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments, checkout

I just wanna integrate to my website Stripe Checkout with Dynamic Data from Firebase Admin.
But it shows like this.

```
IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
```

Here response:

```
.then(response => {
                this.sessionId = response.data
                console.log(response.data);
                
                stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                    
                    sessionId: this.sessionId.id
                
                }).then(function (result) {

                
                });


            })
```

Comment: I see that you log the `response.data` but not the `sessionId` value.  Can you confirm the session ID is actually what you expect it to be?  If you are are returning the full Checkout Session object (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) is there a reason you don't simply redirect the user to the URL directly (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url)?